# Deallocation error after passing vector to function

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Block.h"
#include "veclib.h"
#include "vector3d.h"
#include "concaveop.h"    

using namespace std;    

int main()
{

    //Defining variables    

    vector< vector<Block> > vertex,vertex1;
    vector<long double> polyz;
    vector<long double> polyy;
    vector<long double> polyx;  

    for(k=1;k<dimz+2;k++)
    {
    i[k]=1;

        cout<<"\n\n";

        str="y";

        cout<<"\n";

         while(str == "y" || str == "Y")
         {
          vertex[k].resize(i[k]+1);
          vertex1[k].resize(i[k]+1);

          if(i[k]==1)
          {cout<<"Enter the initial coordinates: ";
          cin>>vertex[k][i[k]].x>>vertex[k][i[k]].y>>vertex[k][i[k]].z;}    

            cout<<"\n\n"<<endl;

            if(str == "n" || str == "N")
            {break;}
            else
            {
            cout<<"Enter the coordinate vector of vertex "<<i[k]<<": ";

            cin>>vertex[k][i[k]].x>>vertex[k][i[k]].y>>vertex[k][i[k]].z;

            cout<<"\nTHE COORDINATES OF VERTEX "<<i[k]<<": ("<<vertex[k] 
            [i[k]].x<<","<<vertex[k][i[k]].y<<","<<vertex[k][i[k]].z<<")\n";
                //}
            }

          }

        //if(str == "n" || str == "N")
        //{break;}

        i[k]=i[k]+1;

    }

       polyx.resize(i[k]); polyy.resize(i[k]); polyz.resize(i[k]);

        //Transferring vertex coordinates

        for(j0=1;j0<i[k]+1;j0++)
        {polyx[j0]=vertex[k][j0].x; polyy[j0]=vertex[k][j0].y; polyz[j0]=vertex[k][j0].z;}

        divToBlocks(i[k],polyx,polyy,polyz);

        cout<<"\n"<<endl;

    }

    k=k-1;

 return 0;

}
```

After executing the code, the error below is occured. I believe that that is a deallocating problem:

```
  Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
```

In ?? () ()
        7  0x00435d54 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator::deallocate (this=0x73f834, __p=0x2cb1310) at C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:110
        C:\Program Files(x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\ext\new_allocator.h:110:3408:beg:0x435d54
        At C:\Program Files(x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\ext\new_allocator.h:110

Comment: Post a [mcve].  Don't describe your code.

Comment: I thought that, in order to express my problem accurately, I have to give background of my code. Also, this is my first question, so please excuse me.

Comment: @UEM Then you should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And you still need to post a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, I will give a try.

Comment: @UEM  We need to see the code to see what you're doing.  What if you are resizing incorrectly?  How would we know if we don't see the code?

Comment: You are write surely, it is my problem. I am a little bit obsesive. Uploading whole code seems a little bit scary for me.

Comment: Hope that it works

Comment: You have trashed your heap, but its impossible to diagnose cos so much code is not there (how big is i for example). Run it under valgrind it will sniff out your error for you

Comment: That is an user input program. i[k] depends on how many inputs the user wants.

Comment: @UEM  `vertex[k]` -- How do you know there are at least k+1 elements in the vector?  More than likely, you are accessing elements out of bounds of the vector.  Use `vector::at ()` instead of `[ ]` to access the elements in the vector, so as to automatically check for out of bounds accesses.

Comment: Just now, I was able to solve the problem. Changing for(j0=1;j0<i[k]+1;j0++) to for(j0=1;j0<i[k];j0++) solved the problem. I know, I could not solve the problem properly and lead you a merry chase. Please forgive me. Thank you all for your helps.